# How can I get devise to add a username with rails 5

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

There are previous posts discussing how to add a username to a devise model. Unfortunately, these posts do not discuss how to setup the views. Mainly, I'm interested in updating the

```
devise/registrations/edit.html.erb
```

file. In it, I have added the following lines

```
<div class="field">
  <%= f.label :username %><br />
  <%= f.text_field :username %>
</div>
```

to allow my users to update their username. Unfortunately, when save the form, the username does not update. Why is this happening?

Comment: When creating a user, is the user properly registered in the database?

Answer (score 0):

I checked your comment above, if you want to update user you can use user controller (not from device registration) and below is some code for user controller

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController

  def edit
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
  end

  def update
    # devise
    if params[:user][:password].blank?
      params[:user].delete(:password)
      params[:user].delete(:password_confirmation)
    end
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    if @user.update_attributes(user_params)
      flash[:success] = 'User Successfully changed'
      sign_out_and_redirect(@user)
      # push the user to sign out
    else
      flash[:error] = @user.errors.full_messages[0]
      redirect_to users_path
    end
  end

  private

  # white list parameter 
  def user_params
    params.require(:user).permit(
      :username, 
      :password, 
      :password_confirmation, 
      :email
  end
end
```

Comment: I currently have no user controller. Are you saying I should put a file user.rb in my app/controllers?

Comment: no user.rb is for model, model is different with controller you should use user contoller

Answer (score -1):

If you follow the instructions from [Devise on Github](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise)
you do not need to add views, but you can customize the ones that are coming with Devise.

I also recommend reading the wiki if you want to change registration or sign in process. All information about custom controllers and how `route.rb` should be are in Devise documentation.